# nhibernate second level cache with implicit transactions

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, second-level-cache

I've read that we can't use 2nd level caching until we use (explicit) transactions - however, we are using a an Informix system - which for reasons currently beyond our control; an accounting system -  we cannot use transactions until we move to SQL server.

Second level caching could greatly improve our performance by cache data that doesn't changed often - is there any way at all to use it with implicit transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, NH won't use the cache without a transaction. But I really wonder why you can't use transactions, which is a good practice not only for NHibernate, but for ANY usage of relational databases.

Comment: I agree totally, but because of another system which we are currently interlinked with, we cannot use transactions. It is part of my new team's job to de-couple them and move to SQL Server (and use transactions!)